# C++ execv no known conversion "const char *[6]" and "char *const *"

Tags: c++, linux, execv

I am trying to call `execv()` with some arguments, `imagePath` and `outputPath` are `std::string` so I converted those to C strings, then I am converting integers to C strings as well.

The error I'm getting is

```
function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char *[6]' to 'char *const *' for 2nd argument
int      execv(const char * __path, char * const * __argv) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

What is the difference between `const char *[]` and `char *const *`?

```
void Utility::ExecCrop()
{
    // convert numbers to strings
    const char* x_char = std::to_string(job.x).c_str();
    const char* y_char = std::to_string(job.y).c_str();
    const char* w_char = std::to_string(job.w).c_str();
    const char* h_char = std::to_string(job.h).c_str();
    
    const char* arguments[] = { imagePath.c_str(), outputPath.c_str(), x_char, y_char, w_char, h_char };

    execv(execPath.c_str(), arguments);
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: The list of `arguments` must be terminated by a `NULL` pointer (or `nullptr` in C++). See the [documentation on the function `execv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) for further information.

Comment: Another side note: How long does temporary values exit in c++? Wouldn't  the temporary `std::string` returned by `std::to_string` evaporate after `.c_str` has been called, and take the buffer with it? Better to bind the string to a variable: `std::string s = std::to_string(foo);  const char *cs = s.c_str();`

Comment: More side notes: By convention, the first argument to an executable should be the name of the execuatable.